# Django. Q objects dynamicaly generate

Tags: python, django, django-q

There is a filter for the model fields

```
queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=search_text) |
            Q(description__icontains=search_text) |
            Q(name_icontains=search_text)
        )
```

How i can do generate block according to circumstances

> Q(title__icontains=search_text) |
>                   Q(description__icontains=search_text)|
>                   Q(name_icontains=search_text)

For example, in one case it is necessary that the filter be such

> Q(description__icontains=search_text) |
>                   Q(name_icontains=search_text)

or

> Q(title__icontains=search_text) |
>                   Q(description__icontains=search_text) |

or

> Q(title__icontains=search_text)

I could generate Q objects using a dictionary
for example

```
search_text = 'somthing text'
fields_name = ['title', 'description', 'name']

 queries = [ Q(**{field+'__icontains': search_text}) for field in fields_name]
```

but how this

`[<Q: (AND: ('title__icontains': 'first'))>,
   <Q: (AND: ('description__icontains': 'first'))>,
   <Q: (AND: ('name__icontains': 'first'))>]`

paste into filter  and use OR separator

Comment: you need what's known as a `parse tree`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
>>>[Q(**{field +'__contains': search_text}) for field in fields_name]
```

Now if you want to do an `OR`

```
>>>import operator
>>>reduce(operator.or_, [Q(**{field+'__contains': search_text}) for field in fields_name])
```

Which is the same as

```
Q(title__icontains=search_text) |
Q(description__icontains=search_text)|
Q(name_icontains=search_text)
```

Comment: Thanks. Fixed question.

Comment: This is what I need