# injecting code inside of code python django and q objects

Tags: python, django, orm

This question gets me close to what I want to do but I am still in need of further understanding. [Django. Q objects dynamicaly generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774659/django-q-objects-dynamicaly-generate)

I have a view in django that looks to see if any query params have been sent to the url. I am expecting some query objects to have multipule values.
ie. `domain.com/?neighborhood=Logan Square&neighborhood=River North`

I grab queryparams and put them in a list. I am now trying to iterate through that list and filter through  the query params using or logic. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q

for this I know I need to use Q objects.

the proper code for this is:

Q(neighborhood='Logan Square') | Q(neighborhood='River North')

so what I need to do is 
1 adding a query Q object dynamically and then also adding the | operator dynamically for all objects in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need this at all. You can simply use `__in`:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(neighborhood__in=request.GET.getlist('neighborhood'))
```

Comment: nice I already have the getlist in a variable so now I just need to set the variable name to the variable that has the neighborhood list! Awesome.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly.
"You may, or may NOT get the query params."?

```
query = ModelName.objects.none()          # setting a Q() instance (maybe skippable)
for a_item in neighbourhood_list:
    query |= (Q(neighborhood = a_item))

query = ModelName.objects.filter(query)
```

You might have to test it, and edit this a little bit, but will do the trick you want.